# Terminal Error Message whilst installing Anbox

Tags: command-line, software-installation

I'm trying to install Anbox, and after several attempts (and complete uninstalls) I'm stuck on the step where I need to "manually load kernels". According to instructions this is done with

$ sudo modprobe ashmem_linux

$ sudo modprobe binder_linux

However, when I do this, I get an error message.

It is perhaps worth noting that I'm currently using a dual boot system with Win10 and Ubuntu 18.04

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu checks module signing by default, on kernels 4.4.0-18.34, 4.4.0-21.37, 4.2.0-42.49, 3.19.0-65.73 and 3.13.0-92.139 onwards.

Because of those changes, DKMS modules will not work on systems with Secure Boot enabled unless correctly configured.

In order to make DKMS work, Secure Boot signing keys for the system must be imported in the system firmware, otherwise Secure Boot needs to be disabled. There are several methods to configure your system to properly load DKMS modules with Secure Boot enabled.

So, you need to install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:morphis/anbox-support
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux-headers-generic anbox-modules-dkms
```

These will add the PPA to your system and install the anbox-modules-dkms package which contains the ashmem and binder kernel modules. They will be automatically rebuild every time the kernel packages on your system update.

After you installed the anbox-modules-dkms package you have to manually load the kernel modules. The next time your system starts they will be automatically loaded.

Then you must run:

```
sudo modprobe ashmem_linux
sudo modprobe binder_linux
```

Read more at [here](https://docs.anbox.io/userguide/install_kernel_modules.html).

Comment: if I disable secure boot, will this affect my dual boot situation in anyway?